# Etherchannel configuration on two differents routers and 1 L3 switch

Tags: cisco, switch, router, etherchannel

Is it possible to configure an aggregation etherchannel between two routers and one L3 switch, means that : the one link in : R1 <-> L3 Switch1 , and the second aggregation link in : R2 <-> L3 Switch1 ? in this topology, the target is that one IP adress will be flapping and shared by the two both separate router aggregate to one L3 switch with one portchannel IP ? if yes, could anyone advise how to do that ?

Comment: That's not how etherchannel works. What you've described is HSRP (cisco) or VRRP (standard). You want R1 and R2 to share the same address in an active/standby role.

Comment: @RickyBeam , here, the purpose is that i have just only IP address to be configured in two differents devise (adding channel member on two differents devise) to aggregate in two link channel member in one switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All the channel members on one end of the channel must be on the same device.
 If you are looking for a single IP address in the switch, you could do that on an SVI and connect layer-2 switch interfaces to the routers, but you do not want duplicate addresses, and you cannot channel to two separate devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... I am looking the way to redundant my router for an interconnection a transit provider. they just allocate 1 IP, so I'm looking the way that single IP could flapping between two differents routers . (when the one goes down, the other take all trafic)

Comment: If you had something like a firewall cluster that may work, but not with a standard router.